# Program ignoring the last row in the file in calculation

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, average, mean

I have a text file with data that looks like this (TestData.txt):

```
Name|Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4|Test5|Test6|Test7|Test8|Test9|Test10
John Smith|82|89|90|78|89|96|75|88|90|96
Jane Doe|90|92|93|90|89|84|97|91|87|91
Joseph Cruz|68|74|78|81|79|86|80|81|82|87
Suzanne Nguyen|79|83|85|89|81|79|86|92|87|88
Richard Perez|100|84|73|81|92|84|95|96|95|100
Ivan Dyer|77|91|90|75|97|94|76|89|90|92
Craig Palmer|91|84|98|89|82|75|78|96|100|97
Madeline Rogers|75|79|78|93|91|76|80|88|100|81
Chelsea Roxas|87|94|89|96|95|85|88|92|86|86
Jasper Bautista|100|83|93|100|98|97|96|97|97|98
Tyler Perez|82|89|90|78|89|96|75|88|90|96
```

My code parses the file and does some calculations with it.

However, in the method `arrangeList()` within which calls another method called `getTestAvg()` (calculates column means), the program ignores Tyler Perez's scores.

I noticed that the results I am getting were inaccurate so I went and printed the whole 2d array with all the test scores and the last column is nowhere to be found.

My entire code is below and I hope someone could point out what causes this.

I keep getting an `IndexOutOfBounds` error whenever I try to switch N (# of students) and M (# of tests) to see what happens. At first, I have 10 students and 10 tests, and all the calculations were correct, but when I added another student, the calculations became inaccurate.

I apologize in advance if my code isn't as well-designed as I'm not an experienced programmer.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestAverages
{
  private static int[] grades;
  private static int[] testTotal;
  private static int N;
  private static double classTotal;
  private static int M;
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    File input = new File("TestData.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
    parseFile(in); 
  }
  
  
  public static void parseFile(Scanner in) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    TestAverages t = new TestAverages();
    in.nextLine(); 
    double total = 0.0;
    
    ArrayList<Double> testScores = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int index = 0;
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
      String line = in.nextLine();
      String[] data = line.split("\\|");
      String name = data[0];
      
      grades = new int[data.length - 1];
      N = grades.length;

      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(data[i + 1]);
        testScores.add((double)grades[i]);
      }
      
      System.out.println(name + "\t");
      System.out.println("Student Average: " + t.getStudentAvg(grades) + "%\n");
      total += t.getStudentAvg(grades);
      
      M++;
      
    }
    t.arrangeList(testScores);
    System.out.printf("\nClass Average: %.1f%%\n", t.getClassAvg(total));
    

    
  }
  
  
  public double getStudentAvg(int[] grades)
  {
    double total = 0.0;
    double avg = 0.0;
    int N = grades.length;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      total += grades[i];}
    
    avg = total / N;
    
    return avg;
  }
  
  
  public double getClassAvg(double total)
  {
    double classAvg = total / M;
    
    return classAvg;
  }
  

  public double[][] arrangeList(ArrayList testScores)
  {
    double[][] tests = new double[N][N];
    
    int len = tests.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
      {
        tests[i][j] = (Double) testScores.get(i*N + j);
      }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      double avg = getTestAvg(tests, i);
      System.out.printf("\nTest " + (i + 1) + " Average: %.1f%%\n", avg);
    }
    return tests;
  }
  

  public double getTestAvg(double[][] testScores, int index)
  {
    double testAvg = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      testAvg += testScores[i][index]; 
    }

    return testAvg / N;
  }
}
```

Here are the numbers I'm supposed to be getting (top) compared to what my program outputs (bottom).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other responses already stated, you had quite the issue with your variables and loops. I now changed N to # of students and M to # of tests to be as you stated in your question.

Next time, maybe try to improve your variable naming, so you don't get confused. (e.g. switch out `n` and `m` for `s` (students) and `t` (tests), if you like your variable names short).

This should work now. Just check against your code to see the changes.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestAverages {
    private static int[] grades;
    private static int n = 0; // amount of students
    private static int m; // amount of tests

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File input = new File("TestData.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
        parseFile(in);
    }

    public static void parseFile(Scanner in) throws FileNotFoundException {
        TestAverages t = new TestAverages();
        in.nextLine();
        double total = 0.0;

        ArrayList<Double> testScores = new ArrayList<Double>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] data = line.split("\\|");
            String name = data[0];

            grades = new int[data.length - 1];
            m = grades.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(data[i + 1]);
                testScores.add((double) grades[i]);
            }

            System.out.println(name + "\t");
            System.out.println("Student Average: " + t.getStudentAvg(grades) + "%\n");
            total += t.getStudentAvg(grades);

            n++;
        }
        t.arrangeList(testScores);
        System.out.printf("\nClass Average: %.1f%%\n", t.getClassAvg(total));
    }

    public double getStudentAvg(int[] grades) {
        double total = 0.0;
        double avg = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            total += grades[i];
        }

        avg = total / grades.length;

        return avg;
    }

    public double getClassAvg(double total) {
        double classAvg = total / n;

        return classAvg;
    }

    public double[][] arrangeList(ArrayList<Double> testScores) {
        double[][] tests = new double[n][m];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                tests[i][j] = (Double) testScores.get(i * m + j);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            double avg = getTestAvg(tests, i);
            System.out.printf("\nTest " + (i + 1) + " Average: %.1f%%\n", avg);
        }
        return tests;
    }

    public double getTestAvg(double[][] testScores, int index) {
        double testAvg = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            testAvg += testScores[i][index];
        }

        return testAvg / n;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a god sent! I've been staring at my screen for hours trying to make sense of where I might be wrong. Thank you so much I really appreciate you helping out!

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
  double[][] tests = new double[N][N];
```

of function arrangeList

you make your test array as N X N.

I believe youh should do something like

```
  double[][] tests = new double[M][N];
```

It's just a suggestion as in your code it seems M = number of students and N = number of tests, differently from what you write in your question.

In general you should review all the method `arrangeList` and probably `getTestAvg` too (loop on N, instead of M), as the loops on variable `len` are intended for a N X N array, which is not the case.

Comment: I already tried that unfortunately. When I do change it to M, I get the IndexOutOfBounds error.

Comment: in fact your should change all your method as it loops only on one index (loops on variable len). Unforntunately i could not review all, since i got no programming env right now

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! I got all my variables mixed and @maloomeister pointed me to the right direction. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the different sizes. I think you want primarily the number of TESTS (not students), but you can't just use `len` for both index bounds.

```
    double[][] tests = new double[N][M];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
      {
        tests[i][j] = (Double) testScores.get(i*N + j);
      }
    }
```

Note that it didn't just resize the array, but it changed the loop conditions to loop the proper amount for inner and outer loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm still getting the same output.